# can't use db:seed in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, seed

I updated my rails gem to 2.3.5 but I keep getting this error when running db:seed:

```
$ rake db:seed --trace
(in c:/Documents and Settings/Owner/workspace/thepatstudio)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:seed'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1728:in `[]'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2050:in `invoke_task'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
c:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
c:/Ruby/bin/rake:19:in `load'
c:/Ruby/bin/rake:19

~/workspace/thepatstudio (master)
    $ rails --version
    Rails 2.3.5
```

My environment.rb has the correct rails version on it and I also ran rake `rails:update`. What can I do?

Comment: check to make sure that you're not using a vendored version of rails.  Are you using version control?  Did you accidentally switch branches?  I do stuff like that all the time.

Comment: What ORM and database are you using? I found this was an issue with not having gems listed in my GemFile

Answer (score 1):

Have you launch the rake task to update your environment after update your gem ?

```
rake rails:update
```